# react native - How to change drawer position base on application language?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, internationalization, react-navigation

I am using react native and react navigation for routing. I have english and arabic language in application. when user switch english to arabic then i am realoading application everything work fine, only drawer position is not get changed.

My code something like this :

```
export default App extends Component {
componentDidMount(){
AsyncStorage.getItem("lang").then(language => {
if(language == "ar"){
   I18nManager.allowRTL(true);
}
})
}

render(){
   return (
      <AppContainer> </AppContainer>
   )
}
}

const AppNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Home: HomeScreen,
    Profile: ProfileScreen,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Home",
    contentComponent: SideMenuScreen,
    drawerPosition: "left"
  }
);
const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

How to change drawer position to right if language is arabic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
const AppContainer = ({ position }) => {
  const AppSide = createAppContainer(
    createDrawerNavigator(
      {
        Home: HomeScreen,
        Profile: SettingsScreen
      },
      {
        initialRouteName: "Home",
        // contentComponent: SideMenuScreen
        drawerPosition: position
      }
    )
  );

  return <AppSide />;
};

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    position: "left"
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    AsyncStorage.getItem("lang").then(language => {
      if (language == "ar") {
        I18nManager.allowRTL(true);
        this.setState({
          position: "right"
        });
      } else {
        this.setState({
          position: "left"
        });
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return <AppContainer position={this.state.position}> </AppContainer>;
  }
}
```

Comment: let me try this

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var position_navbar;

export default App extends Component {


    async componentWillMount(){

    var language = await AsyncStorage.getItem("lang");

      if(language == "ar"){
         I18nManager.allowRTL(true);
         this.setState({position:'leftside'})

      }
     }
    }

    render(){
     position_navbar = this.state.position == 'leftside'?'left':'right'

       return (
          <AppContainer> </AppContainer>
       )
    }
    }

    const AppNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
      {
        Home: HomeScreen,
        Profile: ProfileScreen,
      },
      {
        initialRouteName: "Home",
        contentComponent: SideMenuScreen,
        drawerPosition: position_navbar 
      }
    );
    const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

Comment: const position_navbar is not accessible outside.

Comment: Try to declare the variable globally and call setState

Comment: not working because inital position_navbar is undefined